# Quantitative Economics: Continuity

Tags: continuity

How do I prove that $f(x)=e^x$ is a continuous function at the point $x=0$? I understand that anything raised to the $0$ power equals $1$, therefore it is continuous. But I don't know how to write a proof to show that. Please help.

Comment: Do you have to use the definition of continuity, with $\epsilon$ and $\delta$? You could also show that $lim_{x\rightarrow 0}e^x=1=e^0$.

Comment: Just because $f(0)=1$ doesn't mean it is continuous. What definition are you using for $e^x$?

Comment: I'm not sure. I just typed the question exactly how it appears in the book.

Comment: Yes, just looked. They want me to use Epsilon Delta definition, not the limit definition. I don't know if I am supposed to pick an epsilon, or or show a delta or what... they gave me some absolute values and I'm not sure what to do with it.